# React Navigation conditional rendering still rendering old screen

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux, react-navigation

I'm working on a react native app. When a user isn't logged in I want them to go to the login page, and if they're logged in they can continue to the main app. I'm using react-redux so I can modify state from elsewhere. I'd like for the user to hit a "Log Out" button, I remove their token, and we conditionally render the Login Screen.

However, when I invalidate a token, I'm still hitting code in my LoggedInNav even though I can set a break point and see that my token is null as expected. My LoggedInNav has some code that depends on the auth, so a re-render here is causing a failure. Here is a code snippet:

```
let token == GetTokenFromStore();
<MainStack.Navigator>
        {
          token == null ? (
            <MainStack.Screen 
              name="Login" 
              component={LoginScreen}
              options={{headerShown: false}}
            />
          ) : (
            <MainStack.Screen 
              name="Logged In" 
              component={LoggedInNav}
              options={{headerShown: false}}
            />
          )
        }
        </MainStack.Navigator>
```

Based on my understanding of the react navigation documentation [here](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/auth-flow), LoggedInNav shouldn't be rendered at all once token is null. Why am I seeing a render triggered after nullifying the token?

Comment: Please [edit] the post to include a more complete [mcve]. Basically it seems nothing is triggering the component to rerender but we can't help fix what we can't see.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use `let token` if you want it to re-render when the value changes.

You have to use [state](https://reactnative.dev/docs/state.html).